# Struggling with this connect 4 win

Tags: python, grid

My problem is that I'm checking through a list of possible wins (with lists of each combination inside) and I have this, which checks through the first list in the wins list, and all the elements in it. How can I have it so that this one if statement checks through all the elements? E.g so the 0 represents all the different lists in the wins list and checks them all

for x in wins:

```
    if 'x' in wins[0] and wins[0][0] and wins[0][1] and wins[0][2] and wins[0][3] == 'x':
        print("\nWell done! You've won!")
        menu(
```

Comment: I think I will need to see more of your program to be able to answer this. For a start what is the contents of wins?

Comment: The contents of wins is the different combination of four in a row's within my 6 x 7 grid which is also 6 lists within a list called 'grid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check that all items in each sublist == x.

```
wins = [['x', 'x', 0, 'x'], ['x', 0, 0, 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]

# Iterate over all sublists
for win in wins:
    # Iterate over all elements in list, and check if all equals x
    if all(i == 'x' for i in win):
        # If this is the case - write a message and break out of the loop
        print("Well done! You've won!")
        break
```

If you want to do it your way, you have to fix some problems in your original code. You can't say `if a and b and c and d == 'x'`. This is interpereted by Python like this:

```
if a is not False and
   b is not False and
   c is not False and
   d == 'x'
```

You want to check each individual item, such as:

```
if wins[0][0] == 'x' and wins[0][1] == 'x' and wins[0][2] == 'x' and wins[0][3] == 'x':
```

and then put all of this inside a loop:

```
for sublist in wins:
    if sublist[0] == 'x' and sublist[1] == 'x' and sublist[2] == 'x' and sublist[3] == 'x':
        print("Well done! You've won!")
        break
```

But this is really cumbersome - you should use for loops instead. This is an example that may be more clear:

```
for sublist in wins:
    for item in sublist:
        if item != 'x'
            break
    else:
        print("Well done! You've won!")
        break
```

This code will loop through all your sublists, and then loop through all items in the sublists. If it encounters one item that is not equal to 'x', the inner loop is broken.

At the end of the inner for loop, there is an else clause. This is rarely used feature in Python, but can be really nice to have. The code inside the else clause is only executed if the loop is not broken.

In our case, that means that all of the items equals 'x'.

Comment: I just tried that, loaded up the game, as soon as 'x' was placed into the grid it returned well done, you've won. Needs to be so it detects 4 connected elements

Comment: That worked, but only for the win combination [0] it goes up to 40 odd combinations

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. Been bothering me for ages

Comment: No problem :) I updated the answer with some clarification to why your code didn't work.